# How to find the asymptotically upper bounds for T(n) in the recurrences?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I am wonder how to exactly find the tight upper bound for T(n)?
for one example below:

> T(n)=T( n/2 + n<sup>(1/2)</sup>) + n.

I am not that sure how to use the domain or range transform here.

I use the domain transform here.

let

> n = 2<sup>2<sup>k</sup></sup> ==> n/2 = 2<sup>2<sup>k</sup>-1</sup>
> and n<sup>1/2</sup> = 2<sup>2<sup>k-1</sup></sup>

After that, i do not know how to solve this kind of problem with addition in T(n).
Hope someone can tell me how to solve these kind recurrences.

Thanks Ali Amiri,
As what you said, I approximately consider.

> T(n)=T( n/2 ) + n.

and let,

> n = 2<sup>k</sup>,
>
> ==> T(2<sup>k</sup>)= T(2<sup>k-1</sup>)+ 2<sup>k</sup>

suppose a<sub>k</sub> = T(2<sup>k</sup>)

using domain transform, I get:

> a<sub>k</sub> = 2<sup>k</sup>c<sub>1</sub> + c<sub>2</sub>

hence,

> T(n) = O(n).

Am I right? or still wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think generally n/2 >> n^1/2 so I think we could approximately consider this : T(n) = T(n/2) + n ==> T(n) = 2n

Comment: How can we be sure that we still find the tight bound if we approximately consider like what u said? Thx!

Comment: We cant, as I said I'm not sure, that was something I saw with first look

Comment: Thanks Amiri, I do as what u said. Is the tight upper bound O(n)?

Comment: I wonder if this question is more suitable for http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes Jack, it would be O(n) if what I assume is correct, but I'm not sure that is correct or not, maybe I'm completely wrong, as @NPE said ask this question on cstheory and also ask them if this assumption is correct or not.

Comment: I will ask it on cstheory, thanks for helping me, NPE and Amiri. =D

Comment: Seems cstheory is for research-level, they ask me to ask other place, such as Computer Science which has a broader scope might be suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ali Amiri's intuition is correct, but it's not a formal argument. Really there needs to be a base case like

```
T(n) = 1  for all 0 ≤ n < 9
```

and then we can write

```
 1/2
n    ≤ n/3  for all n ≥ 9
```

and then guess and check a nondecreasing O(n) solution for the recurrence

```
T'(n) = T'(n/2 + n/3) + n
```

and argue that T = O(T') = O(n).